# Redefining ancestor's class method in child class to update 3rd party class dependency

Tags: ruby, class-variables

The **questions** have been placed at the end, as they might not be clear without some context.

#### The purpose

The idea is that we can **dynamically inherit** from `Foo` and **redefine** some of its class dependencies throughout the inheritance chain of a client class (`Bar` > `Baz`). Below a try to reflect this idea:

```
              Foo
               ▼
Bar.foo  -->  FooChild <id: Bar.id)
 ▼                           ↕
Baz.foo  -->  FooChild <id: Baz.id)
```

This approach aims to reuse the class `Foo` by changing its class dependency `id`. So depending on what client class uses `Foo` (or children thereof), `Foo.id` will refer to a different `String` (as reconfigured by `Bar` and `Baz`).

Just for clarity, see below a seemingly more specific example, where the analogy is as follows: `Collection` is to `Foo` as `Room` is to `Bar` and `Library` to `Baz`. If to be at ease we referred to `Foo.id`, in this case we refer to `Collection.item_class`; the class variable of `Collection` that will help to retrieve the *Class* of the *items* of a `Collection` instance object.

```
                     Collection
                         ▼
Room.things     -->  CollectionChild <item_class: Thing)
 ▼                                                  ↕
Library.things  -->  CollectionChild <item_class: Book)
```

We want to define the `things` method (`foo`) **only once** in the parent class `Room` (`Bar`). Rather than redefining the `things` (`foo`) method in the `Library` class (`Baz`), the purpose is to **redefine `item_class` dynamically**.

#### Example

The **code** below synthesizes somehow the *context* of the problem:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    attr_accessor :id
    def resolved_id
      id_class, id_method = id.first
      id_class.send(id_method)
    end
  end
  def identify
    puts "Referring to '#{self.class.resolved_id}'"
  end
end

class Bar
  class << self
    def embed(method, klass:, data:)
      define_method "#{method}" do
        Class.new(klass) {|child| child.id = data}.new
      end
    end
    def id; "bar"; end
  end
  embed :foo, klass: Foo, data: {self => :id}
end

class Baz < Bar
  def self.id; "baz"; end
end

Baz.new.foo.identify
```

The **output** is:

```
Referring to 'bar'
```

I would rather **prefer** to achieve:

```
Referring to 'baz'
```

##### Explanation

1. `Bar` defines a dynamic class method `foo` that creates a child class of `Foo` (let's call it `FooChild`) where `FooChild.id` is initialized with a reference to the `Bar.id` class method.
2. While `Foo` and `Bar` are classes that do **not** belong to the same inheritance chain, `Baz` is a child class of `Bar` and redefines the class method `id`.

#### The problem

While resolving dependencies from within the same inheritance chain gets easy (i.e. redefining methods such as `Bar.id` in `Baz.id`). To resolve dependencies from a non parented class requires to pass the reference to the current class (see `data: {self => :id}`), not just the sym method (`:id`), because the method may not exist or may be unrelated in the class that consumes this dependency.

It may be that the entire approach is incorrect and adds unnecessary complexity, when compared to just explicitly redefining things, rather than trying to make everything configurable and reusable. May be configurable classes can be seen as both: a time savior when used in moderation and an aberration and an anti-pattern when used in excess.

What is difficult is to see when you are crossing the line.

##### The solution I am trying to avoid

In overall, it seems unlikely that this can be resolved without redefining `foo` in the child class `Baz` like this:

```
class Baz < Bar
  def self.id; "baz"; end
  embed :foo, klass: Foo, data: {self => :id}
end

Bar.new.foo.identify
Baz.new.foo.identify
```

The output:

```
Referring to 'bar'
Referring to 'baz'
```

However, if that was the case, that line would look exactly the same as in the parent class `Bar`; just that `self` would refer to a different class.

#### Questions

1. Is there a way to provide a reference to `:id` from `Bar` to `FooChild` (when the method `foo` is generated) that can be redefined from the child class `Baz`? (without redefining `foo` in the child class).
2. After skimming through some `Rails` posts around *constant lookup and resolution*, I am keen to hear some "simpler" yet effective as, alternative methods.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be overcomplicating it a bit. The issue stems from the reference to `self` in the `embed` call on `Bar`.

Since that self happens to be on the class level of `Bar`, it is *frozen* to be `Bar` the moment the line is evaluated.

If you call that self inside the `foo` method instead, it is evaluated at runtime and will be whatever class the method is called on.

```
class Bar
  class << self
    def id; "bar"; end
  end
  def foo
    klass = self.class
    Class.new(Foo) {|child| child.id = {klass => :id}}.new
  end
end
```

Everything else unchanged.

```
Baz.new.foo.identify #=> Referring to 'baz'
```

Comment: Great answer. After modifying `embed` by capturing `self.class` in the defined method itself, it seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

@Siim_Liiser answer is the key solution. This answer has been added just to align his with the original code of the question:

Modified lines with comments:

```
class Bar
  class << self
    def embed(method, klass:, data:)
      define_method "#{method}" do
        # we rather capture the referrer class from the instance object
        referrer = self.class
        Class.new(klass) {|child| child.id = {referrer => data}}.new
      end
    end
    def id; "bar"; end
  end
  # from the referrer class, we just pass the reference :id 
  embed :foo, klass: Foo, data: :id
end
```

The rest of the code remains untouched.

```
Bar.new.foo.identify
Baz.new.foo.identify
```

**Output:**

```
Referring to 'bar'
Referring to 'baz'
```